# XmlDocument.Load Replacing ">"

Tags: c#, xml

When running the following code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        var fileReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(@"C:\Users\username\Desktop\doc.xlf",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read));
        var sourceStream = new MemoryStream(fileReader.ReadBytes((int)fileReader.BaseStream.Length));
        xmlDoc.Load(sourceStream);
    }
```

On a file with a node that looks like this:

```
<source xml:lang="en-us">
        &lt;b>This text is displayed in Bold.&lt;/b>&lt;br>
        &lt;i>This text is displayed in italics.&lt;/i>
</source>
```

The node gets converted to the following when it is read in:

```
<source xml:lang="en-us">
        &lt;b&gt;This text is displayed in Bold.&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;
        &lt;i&gt;This text is displayed in italics.&lt;/i&gt;
</source>
```

In other words, all `>` are being replaced with `&gt;`

Normally that would be OK (and I am even under the impression that it would be technically legal, even if bad practice), but in this case it is **absolutely imperative** that the node not change when it is read in.  Any thoughts on either (1) how to read in the xml to allow `>` or (2) how to work around this issue?  Thanks!

Comment: When you read in the `<source>` node, its content is stored as `"<b>This text is ...</i>"` When you write this string back to an XML file, the original formatting of the node is lost. The original and its copy are still considered equivalent though.

Comment: Why in the world are you using BinaryReader and MemoryStream? Why not just `XmlDocument.Load(File.Open)`?

Comment: That's a good question, John.  I did not write the original code, and that is what it does.  When I went to replicate the issue, I used the same method, just to verify the issue wasn't there (which it wasn't).

Answer (score 6):

Although the right angle bracket is legal in XML, there is no option on `XmlDocument` to avoid changing it to the corresponding entity.

You could use a CDATA section instead:

```
<source xml:lang="en-us">
    <![CDATA[&lt;b>This text is displayed in Bold.&lt;/b>&lt;br>
&lt;i>This text is displayed in italics.&lt;/i>]]>
</source>
```

Comment: I thought that to, but http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax seems to imply that it is technically OK, and http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp explicitly says so...

Comment: [Right angle brackets are allowed in XML text nodes,](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax) as long as they're not part of the string `]]>`.

Comment: @nosirrahcd: You are right. Only `<` is not allowed but `>` is.

Comment: Bummer at there being no way to avoid having it changed... You cannot happen to think of a workaround, can you?  The number one rule in our industry is that we cannot change the <source> node in any way, ever.

Comment: @nosirrahcd: Not really. Maybe you can explain your scenario more clearly? Just reading it in doesn't change the value saved on disk. Do you have to manipulate it somehow and save it again?

Comment: Yes.  We read in the file, parsing out the <source> nodes.  Then we translate them, and put the new text into <target> nodes that correspond to the source nodes.  Then we write that file to disk and send it out.

Comment: @nosirrahcd: Will the translator see "This text is displayed in Bold." or will he see "&lt;b>This text is displayed in Bold.&lt;/b>&lt;br>"?

Comment: If the recipient of the file doesn't use a standards-conform XML parser, then you need a generator that is not standards-conform and matches the proprietary format of the recipient. It's difficult to trick standards-conform generators into generating custom formats.

Comment: +1. Note that there are 2 normalizations (one on read, one on write) even if one does nothing but loads and saves XML. XML parsers *do not* guarantee that original and saved XML are byte-by-byte the same, only identical from XML point of view. Even attributes can be rearranged (in theory).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in XML between `&gt;` and `>` in values of text nodes. So XML parser/DOM is free to represent value in either form as it see fit.

Note that there are other normalizations in XML (whitespace and new lines) which almost guarantee that saved XML will not be byte-by-byte identical to source XML.

If you really need to keep `>` intact try using CDATA, also even that guarantees that text will not be touched - some parsers may let you keep `>` instead of converting to `&gt;` on save.

Real solution is to accept the fact that some characters will be encoded (including non-ASCII characters if saved with encoding that does not directly support) on save to produce valid XML.